# Cannot move controls in the tablelayoutpanel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio 2013.  So far I have a tablelayoutpanel in the Form1.vb[design], I dragged a Textbox(control) from the Toolbox, but I could not move the textbox within the tablelayoutpanel.  What happenes here?  How could I get around with it? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: There's indeed some weird behavior with TableLayoutPanel in design time. You can deal with it typing new values for the Row and Column properties of yor control,  when drag and drop doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to move the `TextBox` within its current cell or move it to a different cell?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I was trying to say I wanted to move the TextBox within the tablelayoutpanel --- within the area of tablelayoutpanel.  I sort of found a hacky way that I  could move the textbox in the panel FREELY..

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem when I was experimenting with TableLayoutPanel.
I couldn't figure out any change in code that might have resulted in this strange behavior but found a way around. Restart Visual Studio! :P

This actually helped and I could move my controls anywhere in the TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties change Anchor to "None".

Comment: Why? How does that help?

Comment: when i was unable to change the location of the control in TableLayoutPane, I changed the Anchor to None then i was able to change the location of the control.

Comment: Please [edit] to augment your answer with this helpful explanation. Can you also explain why this has that effect?